# How to filter tfs in a bag file

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I got a bag file that includes a huge number of a certain tf message. I want to filter out this special message, but all other tf should not be considered? How can I filter out just all tf messages with a certain frame_id and child_frame_id?

Something like

```
rosbag filter source.bag filtered.bag 'topic!="\tf" or m.transforms[0].header.child_frame_id != "odom"'
```

does not work and generates an error message (as expected)

```
AttributeError: '_std_msgs__Header' object has no attribute 'child_frame_id'
```

Thanks for your help

Poseidonius

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50036/how-to-filter-tfs-in-a-bag-file/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2012-12-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try

```
rosbag filter source.bag filtered.bag 'topic!="\tf" or m.transforms[0].child_frame_id != "odom"
```

`child_frame_id` is not in a `header`. This should fix the error you get.

---

Originally posted by [mmedvede](https://answers.ros.org/users/1773/mmedvede/) with karma: 221 on 2012-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on 2012-12-09**:
I should not work at night! Stupid error! Thanks to Mikail!

**Comment by [Hafez Farazi](https://answers.ros.org/users/8891/hafez-farazi/) on 2016-08-29**:
shouldn't it be :

```
rosbag filter source.bag filtered.bag 'topic!="/tf" or m.transforms[0].child_frame_id != "odom"
```